# Package conflict resolution - Conda vs Mamba

Tags: conda, mamba

I'm trying to install packages. First I tried `Conda`:

```
conda -c conda-forge install fiona tensorflow gdal numpy keras geopandas shapely pytorch
...
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
...
```

Then I tried using `Mamba`:

```
mamba -c conda-forge install fiona tensorflow gdal numpy keras geopandas shapely pytorch
...
Summary:

Install: 192 packages
```

Conda output shows dependency conflicts. Mamba does not find any conflicts. The install completes with Mamba.

Which tool is correct here? Will installing with Mamba cause dependency issues later?

Comment: If you ask Conda to update a package, it will check for any inconsistencies. If it doesn't find any with the Mamba-created environment, then that sounds like the Conda solver is wrong.

Comment: `mamba` has received much more work recently - I agree with @merv that if `mamba` finds a solution, it is likely to be correct and conda just has a bug or didn't explore all possible solutions.